# HotChocolate passing different class for Interface for different query in DI

Tags: c#, hotchocolate

I was wondering if it is possible to pass a different class based on the query you're currently on in DI in HotChocolate.

So saying I have an interface like :

```
     public interface IPrinter
        {
            public string Print();
        }
```

and classes that implement the interface :

```
   public class PhysicalPrinter : IPrinter{
    public string Print(){
    //do some stuff
    }


public class Digitalprinter : IPrinter{
        public string Print()
        {
            // do other stuff
        }
    }
```

And I have the following queries :

[image]

Is there any way I can tell HotChocolate to use the PhysicalPrinter when it's inside "**Customer**" and when the query is "**administration**" it will use the DigitalPrinter ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using enums will be solve your problem.

```
public enum UserType
{
    AdminType,
    CustomerType
}

public void Print(UserType userType) 
{
    IPrinter printer;
    switch(userType)
    {
        //write your logic
    }
}
```